# Setting href to dynamic view name

Tags: python, django, hyperlink

```
 {% for stg in statusUrl %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
                <td>{{stg.title}}</td>
                <td>
                  <a href="{% url {{stg.addLink}} %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                   </a>
                

                  <a href="{% url {{stg.editLink}} invoice.id %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                      <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
                    </a> 

                  <a href="{% url {{stg.deleteLink}} invoice.id %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                      <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"></i>
                   </a> 

                  <a href="{% url {{stg.previewLink}} invoice.id %}" class="btn text-secondary px-0">
                      <i class="fas fa-file-invoice"></i>
                   </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Trying to pass `urls.py view` names dynamically to template and then creating hyperlink to each view. How can `href` be adjusted to handle it.

Comment: What  stg.addLink returns ?

Comment: name of the path from urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what stg.addLink  returns but to make it work you need to change

from

```
"{% url {{stg.editLink}} invoice.id %}"
```

to

```
"{% url stg.editLink invoice.id %}"
```

**BUT AGAIN**  it may not work. It depents what **stg.editLink** returns

Comment: it worked , stg.editLink  contain name passed in the urls.py for each path.